# Foreign Key Constrain Fails with "Error creating foreign key on [table] (check data types)"

Tags: mysql

The following query fails with error "Error creating foreign key on city (check data types)":

```
ALTER TABLE  `hotels` ADD FOREIGN KEY (  `city` )
REFERENCES  `mydatabase`.`cities` (`id`)
ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE ;
```

Basically I want to have a ony-to-many relation between city.id and hotels.city.

Here are both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `cities` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `hotels` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `city` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `city` (`city`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Comment: Do the tables already have data in them?

Comment: Hotels is empty, City has some rows that are already constrained with another table (restaurants) in the same way I am trying for hotels above. It worked the first time, but I built the query by hand, without using phpMyAdmin.

Comment: One is `INT`, the other `BIGINT`.

Comment: Did you read the error message? It contains the info to solve the problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The data types need to match:

```
cities.id int(11)
hotels.city bigint(20)
```

Needs to become either:

```
cities.id bigint(20)
hotels.city bigint(20)
```

Or:

```
cities.id int(11)
hotels.city int(11)
```

Depending on what your application needs.

Also worth mentioning is the fact that both need to be either signed or unsigned.

You may need to `OPTIMIZE` your tables after changing the data types to match.

Comment: Right. I have mistakenly changed the data type of hotels.id to match cities.id without realizing that the relationship is in hotels.city. Thank you for the solution!

Comment: @VictorAugusto I menioned that in the last line of the answer.

Comment: signed or unsigned

Comment: NOTE: Match the attribute value also. like `UNSIGNED` or any other which you have in parent table for the column

Answer (score 33):

I was using phpMyAdmin and i tried creating multiple indices on different tables using the relations view. However, I got the same error saying datatypes did not match. However, the cause indeed was that i was giving the same foreign key name to multiple relations, and because of duplicate names, mysql was throwing this error. So rename your relation, and it should work fine.

[image: Foreign Key addition in relations view]

Comment: is this answer or comment?

Comment: This is not a comment, rather a probable answer to this problem

Comment: Me too. I checked everything. The problem was in similarity of foreign key constraint name with other table. Thanks you, you are hero saving me hours.

Comment: this is answer for my solution too

Comment: LOVE YOU BROTHER <3

Comment: Yes, this worked! MySQL error is confusing. The actual problem was with foreign key constraint name!

Comment: Same issue here. The name of the constraint conflicted with another constraint.

Comment: solved my problem, i renamed them and it worked! Thanks

Answer (score 15):

I know this is quite an old thread, but I spent some time with this error as well.

The situation I had was the following one:

`Table 1: administrations (Primary key: AdministrationId)
Table 2: invoices (Foreign key to AdministrationId)
Table 3: users (error pops up while creating foreign key)`

The colomns `AdministrationId` in my `invoices` and `users` table were both of the same type as the `AdministrationId` column in the `administrations` table.

The error on my side was that I tried to create a foreign key called `administration_id` in my `users` table. But a minute before that I already created a foreign key in my `invoices` table also called `administration_id`. When I tried to give the foreign key another name, it worked out fine.

Therefore, keep in mind to correctly name your foreign keys (e.g. prefix them with the table name, eg: `invoices_administration_id` and `users_administration_id`). **Multiple foreign keys with the same name may not exist (within the same database).**

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Another common naming pattern I've seen MySQL clients themselves use while auto-generating FK names, created through the UI is: `sourcetablename_targettablename_fk_1`

Answer (score 5):

I know this has been answered and I know this question is old. However, I just came across this same error with a different cause and, since this is the top result for this error, I thought I would put this information here both for my own use in the future as well as anyone else who happens along after me.

My columns were both bigint and unsigned. However, after first creating the referenced tables, I then went on to change the name of the primary key column. Nothing else about it had changed, but I was unable to create a foreign key relationship. I ended up dropping the referenced tables and recreating them using the column names I desired and I was able to create the foreign key relationships.

Comment: Why not just recreate the FK relation itlsef?

Comment: I was completely unable to create a FK relationship after changing the name of the primary key fields on a couple of tables. The only solution I had was to drop the tables and re-create them. After doing that, I was able to create the FK relationship I wanted.

Comment: I just discovered that if you optimize the tables after making these changes, then it will allow you to create the foreign key relationships without dropping the tables.

Answer (score 4):

Worth mentioning, but the collation should be the same between both table

I faced the same issue with varchar(64) fields in both tables, and It took me some time to identify the problem was coming from the collation field which was not the same between the 2 table fields.

Comment: Thank you. Was getting this error on 2 INT(10) fields that were obviously the same. Did not even consider table collation being a problem, but apparently it is!

Answer (score 2):

Updating `hotels.city` to `unsigned` worked for me. Because `cities.id` is `unsigned`

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to point out, you will get a similar error in case you have set the foreign key to `NOT NULL` and you have set either the `ON DELETE` or `ON UPDATE` to `SET NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

Udating data type `cities.id` `bigint(20)` and `hotels.city` `bigint(20)`
OR
Udating data type `cities.id` `int(11)` and `hotels.city` `int(11)`
AND
Updating `hotels.city` to `unsigned` because `cities.id` is `unsigned`.

Answer (score 0):

If your data types are identical and you're still getting this error, do check the collation / charset of your columns as well, this can easily slip your notice if you're importing data from another server.